# Use of dkh , uid and af_v parameters

Tags: java, android

So I went for an interview and they asked me to figure out how these parameters *dkh, uid* and *af_v* are generated in the given code snippet. The code snippet was decompiled from an apk file.
  Snippet in which I was supposed to search for *dkh* is:-

```
stringbuilder.append("https://track.appsflyer.com/api/v2.3/androidevent?buildnumber=1.15&app_id=").append(context.getPackageName());
    hashmap.put("brand", Build.BRAND);
    hashmap.put("device", Build.DEVICE);
    hashmap.put("product", Build.PRODUCT);
    hashmap.put("sdk", Integer.toString(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT));
    hashmap.put("model", Build.MODEL);
    hashmap.put("deviceType", Build.TYPE);
    obj = com.appsflyer.f.a().b("sdkExtension");
    if (obj == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_386;
    }
    if (((String) (obj)).length() > 0)
    {
        hashmap.put("sdkExtension", obj);
    }
    obj = i(context);
    obj1 = b(context, ((String) (obj)));
    if (obj1 == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_418;
    }
    hashmap.put("channel", obj1);
    if (obj1 == null) goto _L4; else goto _L3
    _L3:
    if (!((String) (obj1)).equals(obj)) goto _L5; else goto _L4
    _L5:
    hashmap.put("af_latestchannel", obj);
    _L37:
    obj = context.getSharedPreferences("appsflyer-data", 0);
    if (!((SharedPreferences) (obj)).contains("INSTALL_STORE")) goto _L7;             
    else goto _L6
    _L6:
    obj = ((SharedPreferences) (obj)).getString("INSTALL_STORE", null);
    _L15:
    if (obj == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_506;
    }
    hashmap.put("af_installstore", ((String) (obj)).toLowerCase());
    obj = h(context);
    if (obj == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_533;
    }
    hashmap.put("af_preinstall_name", ((String) (obj)).toLowerCase());
    obj = g(context);
    if (obj == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_560;
    }
    hashmap.put("af_currentstore", ((String) (obj)).toLowerCase());
    if (s == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_574;
    }
    obj = s;
    if (s.length() != 0)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_585;
    }
    obj = com.appsflyer.f.a().b("AppsFlyerKey");
    if (obj == null) goto _L9; else goto _L8
    _L8:
    if (((String) (obj)).length() <= 0) goto _L9; else goto _L10
    _L10:
    hashmap.put("appsflyerKey", obj);
    if (((String) (obj)).length() > 8)
    {
        hashmap.put("dkh", ((String) (obj)).substring(0, 8));
    }
    s = com.appsflyer.f.a().b("AppUserId");
    if (s == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_666;
    }
    hashmap.put("appUserId", s);
    s = com.appsflyer.f.a().a("userEmails");
    if (s == null) goto _L12; else goto _L11
    _L11:
    obj = new StringBuilder();
    i1 = s.length;
    l = 0;
```

And the code snippet in which I was supposed to search for *uid* is:-

```
   hashmap.put("eventValue", s2);
    if (com.appsflyer.f.a().b("appid") != null)
    {
        hashmap.put("appid", com.appsflyer.f.a().b("appid"));
    }
    s = com.appsflyer.f.a().b("currencyCode");
    if (s == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_987;
    }
    if (s.length() != 3)
    {
        Log.w("AppsFlyer_1.15", (new StringBuilder("WARNING:currency code   

    should be 3 characters!!! '")).append(s).append("' is not a legal    
    value.").toString());
    }
    hashmap.put("currency", s);
    s = com.appsflyer.f.a().b("IS_UPDATE");
    if (s == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_1013;
    }
    hashmap.put("isUpdate", s);
    hashmap.put("af_preinstalled", Boolean.toString(j(context)));
    s = a(context.getContentResolver());
    if (s == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_1055;
    }
    hashmap.put("fb", s);
    a(context, ((Map) (hashmap)));
    s = com.appsflyer.k.a(context);
    if (s == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_1082;
    }
    hashmap.put("uid", s);
    _L28:
    try
    {
        hashmap.put("lang", Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());
    }
    // Misplaced declaration of an exception variable
    catch (String s) { }
    try
    {
        s = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService("phone");
        hashmap.put("operator", s.getSimOperatorName());
        hashmap.put("carrier", s.getNetworkOperatorName());
    }
    // Misplaced declaration of an exception variable
    catch (String s) { }
    s = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService("connectivity");
    if (!s.getNetworkInfo(1).isConnectedOrConnecting()) goto _L18; else goto    

   _L17
```

And for *af_v* is:-

```
    public final void run()
    {
    String s2 = com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib.a(a);
    Object obj = (Context)d.get();
    if (obj == null) goto _L2; else goto _L1
    _L1:
    String s = com.appsflyer.f.a().a(((Context) (obj)));
    if (s == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_70;
    }
    if (s.length() > 0 && a.get("referrer") == null)
    {
        a.put("referrer", s);
    }
    Map map;
    boolean flag1;
    flag1 = "true".equals(((Context) (obj)).getSharedPreferences("appsflyer- 
    data", 0).getString("sentSuccessfully", ""));
    s = (String)a.get("eventName");
    map = a;
    Object obj1;
    boolean flag;
    if (s == null)
    {
        flag = true;
    } else
    {
        flag = false;
    }
    map.put("counter",  

   Integer.toString(com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib.a(((Context) (obj)), flag)));
    flag = flag1;
   _L5:
    obj = a;
    if (!flag)
    {
        flag = true;
    } else
    {
        flag = false;
    }
    ((Map) (obj)).put("isFirstCall", Boolean.toString(flag));
    s = (String)a.get("appsflyerKey");
    if (s == null)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_195;
    }
    if (s.length() != 0)
    {
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_204;
    }
    Log.d(s2, "Not sending data yet, waiting for dev key");
    return;
    new j();
    Object obj2 = a;
    obj = (String)((Map) (obj2)).get("appsflyerKey");
    String s1 = (String)((Map) (obj2)).get("af_timestamp");
    obj2 = (String)((Map) (obj2)).get("uid");
    obj = com.appsflyer.j.a((new StringBuilder()).append(((String)   
    (obj)).substring(0, 7)).append(((String) (obj2)).substring(0, 
    7)).append(s1.substring(s1.length() - 7)).toString());
    a.put("af_v", obj);
    obj = com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib.b(a);
    try
    {
        com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib.a(c, ((String) (obj)), s, d, null, s2,   
    b);
        return;
    }
    catch (IOException ioexception)
    {
        s = ((String) (obj));
        obj1 = ioexception;
    }
    _L3:
    if (s != null && d != null && !c.contains("&isCachedRequest=true"))
    {
        Log.e(s2, ((IOException) (obj1)).getMessage(), ((Throwable)  
    (obj1)));
        com.appsflyer.a.a.a().a(new b(c, s, "1.15"), (Context)d.get());
        return;
    } else
    {
        return;
    }
    obj1;
    Log.e(s2, ((Throwable) (obj1)).getMessage(), ((Throwable) (obj1)));
    return;
    obj1;
    s = null;
      goto _L3
    _L2:
    flag = false;
    if (true) goto _L5; else goto _L4
    _L4:
    }
    }
```

After a long research over internet all I  could get to know that these parameters and .java files to which these snippets belong are a part of **AppsFlyer** SDK and integrated with the application for the tracking purpose of no. of users downloading the application and other mobile ad tracking activities. 
Also I know the purpose of *hashmap.put* method but don't know the exact use of this here in this code. 
So my question is how these three parameters are generated and their purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**dkh:**

We can see from the snippet below that `dkh` is just the first 8 characters of the AppsFlyer key.

```
obj = com.appsflyer.f.a().b("AppsFlyerKey");
// [...]
if (((String) (obj)).length() > 8)
{
    hashmap.put("dkh", ((String) (obj)).substring(0, 8));
}
```

As for how it used- in the code you posted, it isn't. Given that the code you posted starts off with creating a `StringBuilder` that is initialized with a URL, it is probably a safe guess that the hashamp that is being built is also related to that URL.

When dealing with API calls, the most common use for a hashmap is as HTTP parameters (e.g. via GET or POST). Thus my assumption is that all these hashmap entries are simply parameters sent to the AppsFlyer API. Some are used to provide information about the user's device, and some (such as `dkh`) are probably used by AppsFlyer to associate the device information with your account.

**uid**

The code snippet doesn't provide enough information to glean anything meaningful about how `uid` is generated. All we really know is that it isn't null and if comes from some other function in the AppsFlyer SDK based on this snippet:

```
s = com.appsflyer.k.a(context);
// [null check]
hashmap.put("uid", s);
```

Given the context of `dkh` above and the general consensus amongst programmers that "uid" stands for "user ID," I would assume this is a user identifier that will also be sent to the API.

**af_v**

I think applying some formatting to the code snippet will help:

```
obj = (String)((Map) (obj2)).get("appsflyerKey");
String s1 = (String)((Map) (obj2)).get("af_timestamp");
obj2 = (String)((Map) (obj2)).get("uid");
obj = com.appsflyer.j.a(
    new StringBuilder()
        .append(((String) (obj)).substring(0, 7))
        .append(((String) (obj2)).substring(0, 7))
        .append(s1.substring(s1.length() - 7))
   .toString()
);
a.put("af_v", obj);
```

Starting from the top, we know that `obj` is our AppsFlyer key again. `s1` is a timestamp of some sort. `obj2` is our uid from above.
The String that we end up putting into `af_v` is made up of these three parts:

- the first 7 characters of the AppsFlyer key (`obj1`)
- the first 7 characters of the uid (`obj2`)
- the last 7 characters of the timestamp

Again, this is probably all just sent to the API, and the real use is known only to people on the AppsFlyer team. It might be an identifier for a particular request- the fact that it is based on a particular user, timestamp, and API key means that it is likely fairly unique for each request and squishing (only part of) them together into one string probably isn't particularly useful data for anyone to look at.

Comment: Thanks! this helped me a lot.